# Setting up magento 2 on codenvy with apache 2

Tags: apache-http-server, magento

I'm playing with codenvy and trying to get an existing magento 2 project on it. So far I have cloned the project directory and imported the database to mysql. I've been stuck on getting it to run on the apache server however. The problem is that codenvy dynamically generates the url every time you restart the server and I'm unsure if I'm able to change that to the static url I have specified in my database, vhosts, and hosts file? Does anyone have any experience trying something like this?